# gwt detach list

Tags: gwt

can anyone explain me, what that detach list is, which can be found so frequently in the web "A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list". I could not find an explanation or any background information, only the error message.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As part of [memory leak mitigation](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/DomEventsAndMemoryLeaks) (which is mostly, if not only, needed in IE), GWT has a concept of *attached* and *detached* widgets. Whenever you add a widget as a child to another *attached* widget, the child widget and all its child widgets become *attached* too, and reciprocally when you remove a widget from its *attached* parent, then it's *detached* along with all its children. When a widget is detached, it should free all resources that could cause memory leaks.

The above builds trees of *attached* widgets, but a tree needs a root. There are two kinds of such root *attached* widgets:: `RootPanel`s are always attached, and widgets created by `wrap()`ping an existing DOM element are automatically *attached* too.

When the page unloads, GWT makes sure to detach all widgets to avoid memory leaks. For that, it tracks the *root attached* widgets in what's called the *detach list*, and it ensures that widgets that are supposed to be *root* widgets actually are roots (i.e. their element is not contained within the DOM subtree of another widget). The only exception to this rule is `RootPanel.get()` because it represents the `<body>` of the document in which all other widgets live.

Comment: Hi Thomas,

So ok that's great there are an attached widgets trees. let's say that's an implementation detail. What is the best way to transparently access an element by id (independently of the element being attached or detached).
Also, better that a RootPanel it gives sens to have typed GWT widgets in trees, but how do we access that registry centrally? Is there a Document.getWidgetById() : Widget method somewhere?

Comment: Because the code is rather raw : it relies on indirect assumptions: in
RootPanel.isElementChildOfWidget(Element element) we see this note:
     Walk up the DOM hierarchy, looking for any widget with an event listener set. Though it is not dependable in the general case that a widget will have set its element's event listener at all times, it *is* dependable if the widget is attached. Which it will be in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The detach list is the list of widgets to be detached when the page unloads ([source](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RootPanel.html#detachOnWindowClose%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29), guess only one of the sources).
Basically (the following is not a complete explanation, GWT is very well documented if you are willing to read the official google documentaion), in GWT, when you create a Widget, that widget is not shown until it is added to the RootPanel, or the any widget (which becomes its parent) which is attached to the RootPanel. There are operations (such as the one I pointed you as a link earlier) which cause a widget to be detached from the RootPanel; however, you cannot call `RootPanel.detachNow(widget)` on a widget which is embedded in a parent one. Such call will cause the exception you are asking for.